# Gráfico Roda da Vida

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Estou procurando um tutorial, plug in JQuery ou código para um Gráfico no formato "Roda da Vida", como na imagem abaixo.
Não haverá animação, mas os dados serão dinâmicos, vindos de uma aplicação PHP/MySQL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada área é dividida em 10 pedaços, que representam a média da nota para cada área (de 0 a 10). A média será exibida "colorindo" a quantidade correspondente dessa média, vinda do PHP.

Agradeço qualquer ideia ou samplecode que possa ajudar.

Comment: O mais próximo que encontrei foi [esse](http://kreese.net/blog/2012/08/26/d3-js-creating-a-polar-area-diagram-radial-bar-chart/). Você conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Sim, consegui usando o formato "Polar" da API: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar. Obrigado!

Comment: Então escreva sua resposta e marque ela como aceita.

Comment: Este foi o melhor que eu encontrei até agora: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/interactive-wheel-life-chart/